# How do I open file under cursor, when the filename has a trailing dot?

Tags: linux, filesystem, error

There is a file with name `./folderA/folderB/file.`.

And there is text:

```
./folderA/folderB/file.:abcdefg
```

When I move the cursor on letter `B` and type `<c-w>f`, it says

```
E447: Can't find file "./folderA/folderB/file" in path
```

Note that the file name is `file.`. There is a dot at the end of the file name but no extension name.

How can I open such a file? I have many files with similar names, so I hope to minimize keystrokes. I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to set `includeexpr`. From `:help includeexpr`:

```
                                                *'includeexpr'* *'inex'*
'includeexpr' 'inex'    string  (default "")
                    local to buffer
                    {not in Vi}
                    {not available when compiled without the
                    |+find_in_path| or |+eval| features}
    Expression to be used to transform the string found with the 'include'
    option to a file name.  Mostly useful to change "." to "/" for Java:
            :set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\\.','/','g')
    The "v:fname" variable will be set to the file name that was detected.

    Also used for the |gf| command if an unmodified file name can't be
    found.  Allows doing "gf" on the name after an 'include' statement.
    Also used for |<cfile>|.

    The expression will be evaluated in the |sandbox| when set from a
    modeline, see |sandbox-option|.

    It is not allowed to change text or jump to another window while
    evaluating 'includeexpr' |textlock|.
```

The "Also used" paragraph is what will be useful here. When you do a `gf` and vim can't find the file, it places the name it tried to read in `v:fname` and evaluates the expression in `includeexpr`. it then tries to read a file with the resulting name. So if you do a:

```
:set includeexpr=v:fname.'.'
```

then do a `gf` when on `file.`, vim tries to read `file`, which fails. It then evaluates `v:fname.'.'`, with `v:fname` set to `file`, which just appends a period to the contents of `v:fname` and returns `file.`. vim then tries to read that, which succeeds.

Note that vim will still try to read `file`, so if you have both `file` and `file.`, vim will read `file`, but I'd argue having both `file` and `file.` is just asking for trouble. :-)

If you only need to do this for certain file types, you could place it in an `autocmd`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.dots set includeexpr=v:fname.'.'
```

where you only want to have vim look for `file.` in files ending in `.dots` (for example).

Answer (score 7):

From `:help gf`:

```
Trailing punctuation characters ".,:;!" are ignored.
```

So I suppose the dot at the end is not considered as part of the filename but as punctuation.

I don't know if it can be done with fewer keystrokes, but to open this file while the cursor is on B, I would type:

`viWF.<c-w>f`

- `viW` = visually select characters inside big word
- `F.` = move the end of the selection to the previous dot
- `<c-w>f` = open file whose path is visually selected in a split

To save some keystrokes you could also define a mapping :

```
nnoremap <leader>wf viWF.<c-w>f
```

Then type `<leader>wf` while the cursor is on the file path you described.

Comment: @user3813057 You could also set `includeexpr`. In my .vimrc I have `set   includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'[-:]\\d\\+[-:]\\?$','','')`, which strips trailing numbers when a `gf` fails (for dealing with things like error messages in the form `<file>-<line>: error`). You could do something similar here.

Comment: @blm If you have the time, you should post it as an answer, maybe explaining a little how it works. It probably deserves its own answer.

Comment: Ok, turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is very, very good for a detailed, script-oriented way to accomplish a micro-optimization of a corner case, but many people in the same scenario don't want to be forced into a vimrc customization and those people usually also wouldn't have "many, many files" where saving two keystrokes is important and they still want a general and simple way to accomplish what you're describing.  So the simple and obvious solution for those people, and perhaps for you as well, is Vim's Visual Mode `gf`.

Do a Visual Mode select of the text representing the weird file name, for example let's say with `vww` or `v$`, then type `gf`. Done. Visual Mode `gf` exists to cover the situation you're describing. Sure it changes a 2 keystroke combination into a 4 or 5 one, but it also works perfectly and visually and it works for this case as well as other similar cases, like let's say spaces in the file name.